# What is candlebox? No info in the dictionaries

Tags: meaning, literature

Joseph Conrad, "Youth":

> In two days it blew a gale. The Judea, hove to, wallowed on the Atlantic like an old ***[candle-box](https://books.google.it/books?id=ND04AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=candle%20box%20on%20old%20ships&source=bl&ots=8eJbejt7yB&sig=ACfU3U1W0qD6ecWJyZ7_ac8-0CfKUuhF3Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8-_D_18rjAhU_VRUIHVICADYQ6AEwEnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=candle%20box%20on%20old%20ships&f=false)***.

It might appear to be a strange question, but see for yourself:

no results in Oxford [1](https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&dictionary=en&query=candlebox), [2](https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&dictionary=en&query=candle%20box) and Webster [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candlebox), [2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candlebox). A strange [band](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/candlebox) in the Free Dictionary. No results in other dictionaries as far as I got. No results in Google except for the band even with "-band" function and other similar functions.

Would you please point out to me what "candle-box" means?

Comment: Out of context I thought it might be a [candle lantern](https://www.koch.com.au/lanterns-hanging-candle-holders), but that doesn't seem to fit the context of your quote. There are lots of search results for "candle box" as a two-word phrase, but most of them seem to be related to packaging for candle sales and mailing, which of course doesn't seem to fit your quote either.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, a box for holding candles! Why the ship should be compared to that kind of box rather than any other kind, I don't know.

Comment: @KateBunting I guess is is one of the kind of boxes that would be common enough on ships, where everything has to be stowed away, not left rolling about, but possibly also a foreshadowing of the later spontaneous combustion of the Judea's cargo.

Comment: @KateBunting possibly also referencing back to the 'gravediggers' work' they had to do by light of tallow-dips to right the sand ballast when they got caught in a storm coming up from London. .

Comment: The inestimable resource [Furniture Glossary.com](http://www.furniture-glossary.com/Candle-Box.php) has: 'What is the meaning of the furniture term Candle Box? _Answer_: Tall hanging box of wood or tin, used for keeping candles.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read this particular book, so I *might* be missing some context, but there are good reasons to think that **candle-box** in this case does refer simply to a box for candles (as Kate Bunting and Spagirl suggested above).

Heaving to is a common tactic for sailing ships to survive a storm. When a sailing vessel is [hove to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaving_to), it has very little forward motion, but just drifts slowly downwind, sideways. It will roll about on the waves in an irregular and ungainly fashion, compared to a boat making way under sail. So Conrad's simile suggests that the *Judea* appears more like a square-shaped box, after heaving to, than like a sleek craft that can glide through the ocean.

A Google Image Search for **old candle box** returns a lot of oddly shaped open wooden boxes for candles, [like this one](https://www.adverts.ie/other-antiques-collectables/old-wooden-candle-box/16788031), which would just about float if jettisoned from a ship, but would be very liable to wobble or tip when dropped into choppy seas. A search for a **ship's candle box** returns images like [the one here](https://www.rubylane.com/item/357005-RL180132/19th-Century-Ship-Captains-Candle-Box78), which would float well, but have low stability and be liable to tipping.

A candle-box (whether maritime or onshore) would have been a very familiar object in the 19th century - so I think Conrad's metaphor would have been very clear to contemporary readers.

Comment: The text of the story also makes reference to the Judea having a very square stern, so she is already a box-like vessel.

Comment: The points in comments above, that the choice specifically of a 'candle' box hints a later cargo fire on the ship, are probably valid too - but I think it's clear that the basic image is of a wooden box wallowing unstably in the ocean.

Comment: *OED* does have this definition for "candle-box".

Comment: @Spagirl ...  I didn't think you were quibbling :D I've  upvoted your comment (my comment was about the comments on the question at the top of the page, it just happened to land at the same time as yours!)

Comment: Ah, okay... I was a bit confused!

Comment: I often confuse myself too

Comment: Thank you. When I open the link to the old candle box image, it gives me a mistake. Could you probably replace it with another link?